# How to get the physical screen dimensions on android chromebook?

Tags: android, chromebook

I am trying to get the physical screen dimensions of the android chromebook screen using the following code:-

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
sketchActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

This is returning the size of the window in which the app is hosted. So when my app window is not fullscreen then the values returned by this API are smaller than the actual screen size.

So can anyone tell me how the correct dimensions of the physical screen?

Comment: Could you try this :  Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; similarly for height as well

Comment: I have a similar problem, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164189

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to find solution for my own question.
Below is the code I used: -

```
public static Point getDisplaySize() {
    boolean isChromeBook = SketchApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(DEFAULT_CHROMEBOOK_PACKAGE_NAME);
    if (isChromeBook) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = SketchApplication.getAppContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return new Point(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
    } else {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)sContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getRealSize(size);
        return new Point(size.x, size.y);
    }
}
```

This function returns the real dimensions of the device screen.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There is still the same gap (missing some height from the display).